Example of a WKT text of a topocentric CRS with Cartesian origin different from zero
My WKT text:
PROJCRS["EPSG topocentric PMRP",  
    BASEGEOGCRS["SIRGAS 2000",  
        DATUM["Sistema de Referencia Geocentrico para las AmericaS 2000",  
            ELLIPSOID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,  
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],  
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,  
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]], 
        ID["EPSG",4674]],  
    CONVERSION["EPSG topocentric example A",  
        METHOD["Geographic/topocentric conversions",  
            ID["EPSG",9837]],  
        PARAMETER["Latitude of topocentric origin",-21.18333333,  
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],  
            PARAMETER["False easting",150000.000,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1.0]],  
            ID["EPSG",8834]],  
        PARAMETER["Longitude of topocentric origin",-47.8,  
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],  
            PARAMETER["False northing",250000.000,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1.0]],  
            ID["EPSG",8835]],  
        PARAMETER["Ellipsoidal height of topocentric origin",544.8,  
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],  
            ID["EPSG",8836]]],  
    CS[Cartesian,3],  
        AXIS["topocentric East (U)",east,  
            ORDER[1],  
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],  
        AXIS["topocentric North (V)",north,  
            ORDER[2],  
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],  
        AXIS["topocentric height (W)",up,  
            ORDER[3],  
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],  
    USAGE[  
        SCOPE["unknown"],  
        AREA["To be specified"],  
        BBOX[-90,-180,90,180]],  
]  

But the origin of the Cartesian system is still 0,0,0. Where is my error?

Could you describe the problem a bit more detailed? See [tour]

I want a SRC Topocentric with cartesian origin (false north=250000 and false east=150000). But the WKT above returns cartesian origin  (false north=0 and false east=0). The "PARAMETER["False northing",250000.000,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1.0]]," and "PARAMETER["False easting",150000.000,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1.0]]," is not working.
